# Creating bibliographies with biblatex and moderncv

Tags: biblatex, moderncv

I wanted to use the moderncv class together with biblatex. To this end, I redefined the `bibliography` bibenvironment

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}{}{}%
{\cvline{\printfield[labelnumberwidth]{labelnumber}}%
{}
}
```

The labels were adjusted correctly, but the text of the bib entry (unsurprisingly) started below the label, took the whole line and was not adjusted at all.

My question is if there is a neat solution for this, or if one must define a new `BibliographyDriver` as is done  here [Sorted list of publications in moderncv from bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85965/sorted-list-of-publications-in-moderncv-from-bibtex/85981#85981) or even resort to some low level hackery as in this answer [tabular bibliography with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71088/tabular-bibliography-with-biblatex/71454#71454)? If so, what do I have to do?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`\defbibenvironment` pretty much takes the same arguments as `\newenvironment`. For the standard numeric styles the default bibliography environment is defined in `numeric.bbx`. You can adapt this definition to use the list layout parameters for `moderncv`'s `thebibliography` environment. The following document takes the parameters from `moderncvstyleclassic.sty`.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{% label format from numeric.bbx
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}% layout parameters from moderncvstyleclassic.sty
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{\hintscolumnwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \leftmargin\labelwidth%
      \advance\leftmargin\labelsep}%
      \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\moderncvstyle{classic}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}       
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\nocite{companion,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography[title={Publications}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the shamelessly lazy copiers, `biblatex` requires the `.aux` to be compiled with biber instead of bibtex.

Comment: @anderstood I cannot understand your comment. Can you go into more details? After compiling the above code I don't get the list of publications.

Comment: @Veliko If you compile in a terminal (typing e.g. "pdflatex document.tex"), you should compile the bibliography using "biber document" and _not_ "bibtex document". If you are using an editor (texmaker, texnicenter, etc.) you should probably change your configuration settings.