# Class modernCV with German bibliography biblatex; Same Author replaced by dash

Tags: biblatex, moderncv

I have found a solution for using modernCV with biblatex [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123805/creating-bibliographies-with-biblatex-and-moderncv):

only problem is: when using the biblatex-style "verbose-inote" There is some empty space after the dash, that replaces the author's name, when mentioned already. Is there a way to display the entry correctly without that empty space? Thank you.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\list
{\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{% label format from numeric.bbx
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
{\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}% layout parameters from moderncvstyleclassic.sty
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{\hintscolumnwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
    \leftmargin\labelwidth%
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep}%
\sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000}
{\endlist}
{\item}

\moderncvstyle{classic}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}       
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\nocite{companion,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography[title={Publications}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `dashed=false`? What do you mean by 'display correctly'? Can you show us a full MWE that reproduces the behaviour? The linked answer does not use `biblatex`.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. The link is now corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redefine `\bibnamedash`, the default definition gives a very wide box due to your large \leftmargin.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\list
{\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{% label format from numeric.bbx
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
{\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}% layout parameters from moderncvstyleclassic.sty
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{\hintscolumnwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
    \leftmargin\labelwidth%
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep}%
\sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000}
{\endlist}
{\item}
\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{\mbox{\textemdash\space}}%
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\nocite{companion,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography[title={Publications}]
\end{document}
```

[image]