# Article is already a type "wizard-defined" function name

Tags: bibtex, moderncv, texworks

Following this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85983/17685 I'm trying to create a publication list with `TeXworks`.

Basically I did exactly what was in the answer and created two `files plainyr_my.bst` and `Publication.tex`. Then I compile `Publication.tex` into pdfLaTeX. Then I compile `Publication.tex` into BibTeX and see:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012)
The top-level auxiliary file: Publications.aux
The style file: plainyr_my.bst
article is already a type "wizard-defined" function name
---line 592 of file plainyr_my.bst
 : function {article
 :                  }
Database file #1: Publications.bib
(There was 1 error message)
```

What is wrong?

P.S. I can add the files content to the question, but I'm afraid that it would be inappropriate here, since they are too long.

Comment: You can't have two definition for `function {article}`

Comment: @egreg, Oh. I really did this mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.

By mistake I have added `function {article}` two times.