# Bibtex JabRef and moderncv

Tags: bibtex, texmaker, moderncv

I am trying to create my cv using moderncv class. Everything look fine until the publication section. I have a publication database under the title "publications.bib" that is created in JabRef. I want to use import the publications included in this database in my cv. I tried to modify the `plainyr.bst` file like here [Sorted list of publications in moderncv from bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85965/sorted-list-of-publications-in-moderncv-from-bibtex) but did not work, apparently it leaves the section empty. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{grey}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

\end{filecontents}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\nopagenumbers{}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\firstname{E}
\familyname{Xample}
\begin{document}

\section{Publications}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{moderncv}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Even when I don't use the `.bib` and work just like in the first answer of the above link, having:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}       

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  journal = {Good Journal},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}

\end{filecontents}

\firstname{E}
\familyname{Xample}
\begin{document}

\section{Publications}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainyrrev}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

In the pdf file, I get just printed the section "Publications" and nothing is included in that. However, a `.bib` file is created that has the entry of the article.

Any idea?

Comment: You're pulling in `\jobname.bib`, which is not the same as `publications.bib`. Why not just use `\bibliography{publications}`? Note that JabRef is just a manager of BibTeX items. You should still compile the `.bib` file using BibTeX or [`biber`](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/) (if you're using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

Comment: When I put publications.bib I get a mispelling error. Everytime I compile it, it replaces the .bib file with an empty file.

Comment: I bibtex the file inside TexMaker. \bibliography{publications} compiles, but adds nothing to the cv

Comment: Drop the `filecontents` part of the setup, since you don't need that.

Comment: When I skip the `filecontents` part and still have the publication sections as in the MWE but with `\bibliography{\publications}` I get a mispelling error again ! `Undefined control sequence. <write> \string \bibdata {\publications} l.102 \bibliography{\publications}`

Comment: You would need `\bibliography{publications}`, not `\bibliography{\publications}`.

Comment: Right. It was a typo. Still with `\bibliography{publications}` nothing is added to the Publication section.

Comment: `\bibliography{publications}` tell TeX that you're using a bibliography named `publications.bib`. Compile your `file.tex` once (`latex file`), and then compile `bibtex file`, and then again `latex file`.

Comment: That's exactly what I do. Seems strange. I have done this many times before, outside `moderncv` class and it worked. Now if I just use `bibliography{\publications}` I get errors `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \@firstname {}~\@lastname {} l.6 \begin{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem was. Everytime I change the `.bib` file, I have to change into the `.aux` file the line that defines the style `\bibstyle{moderncv}` to `\bibstyle{plainyr}`. Then I compile the `.bib` file and then I create the pdf. Everything works fine!