# How can I call a macro within \tldatelabelcventry

Tags: biblatex, moderncv, moderntimeline

**Edit: MWE added.**

**Edit2: Provided working intermediate MWE.**

I am using [`moderncv`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv) with [`moderntimeline`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderntimeline) package.

I wanted to include a hack from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85981/6908 to display publications in the same format as the rest of the CV. This works nicely except that I want it work with the `moderntimeline` package.

However, I am unable to succeed. I think it has to do with an expansion problem.

This is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}  
\usepackage[firstyear=1996,lastyear=2018]{moderntimeline}
\tlwidth{0.8ex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[url=false,backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
    doi=false,  
    isbn=false,
    backref=false, 
    sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

%remove brackets from year
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]}{\printtext}{}{}

% remove year from the author bibmacro
\xpatchbibmacro{author}{%
 \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}
 {}{}{}

%change order and wrap into \cvline
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
\cvline{\usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}%
  }

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% personal data
\name{Joe}{Smith}

\moderncvstyle{classic}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}                              

\begin{document}

\nocite{bertram}
\printbibliography[title={Publications}]                       
\end{document}
```

Changing the `\cvline` to `\tldatelabelcventry` from the `moderntimeline` package as follows

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}  
\usepackage[firstyear=1996,lastyear=2018]{moderntimeline}
\tlwidth{0.8ex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[url=false,backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
    doi=false,  
    isbn=false,
    backref=false, 
    sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

%remove brackets from year
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]}{\printtext}{}{}

% remove year from the author bibmacro
\xpatchbibmacro{author}{%
 \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}
 {}{}{}

%change order and wrap into \cvline
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
\tldatelabelcventry{
 2006 % actual year from bibitem
    }{
    2006 % Label of year (should be the same)
    }{
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  %\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}
  %
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}{}{}{}%
  }

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% personal data
\name{Joe}{Smith}

\moderncvstyle{classic}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}                              

\begin{document}

\nocite{bertram}
\printbibliography                       
\end{document}
```

yields the following result

[image]

which is great except that the year is hardcoded.

What do I need to change to make it work with the actual year of the bibitem?

I tried using `\usebibmacro{date+extrayear}` with no succees.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Oh you're right...

Comment: You could try adding a `\protect`, but without a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) I can't test it.

Comment: OK MWE added @PeterGrill

Comment: Is the MWE as posted supposed to compile fine? It doesn't for me. I get `Undefined control sequence. <argument> \@firstname {}~\@lastname {}`.

Comment: It did. Now it doesn't.

Comment: @PeterGrill fixed now normally...

Comment: I don't get an error if I replace `\cvline` to `\tldatelabelcventry`. Perhaps you just need to delete the `.aux` files from a previous run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14702/discussion-between-trefex-and-peter-grill).

Comment: @PeterGrill it doesn't compile once you compile 2-3 times in a row.

Comment: Maybe you should make it more clear when this does and doesn't run for you. If I replace `\cvline{\usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}{%` by `\tldatelabelcventry{2006}{%` then I get errors and no dvi file.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Thank you for the tip. I know provided a version that works with `\tldatelabelcventry` only the years are hardcoded.

Comment: @Trefex Great, much better. Just one more question (I don't know anything about the packages you're using): Do you really need only the year? `\usebibmacro{date+extrayear}` sounds like it would produce a formatted date.

Comment: @StephanLehmke I do only need the year yes, but I'm not sure how to access that field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the packages `biblatex` and `moderntimeline` which are supposed to work together here, this seems to be a hopeless case at first glance.

All the `biblatex` user macros are as unexpandable as can be, while the `pgfmath` computations needed for the timeline seem to require expandability.

I'm getting seemingly acceptable results with the following approach:

```
%change order and wrap into \cvline
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
\tldatelabelcventry{
 \thefield{year}% actual year from bibitem
    }{
    \thefield{year}% Label of year (should be the same)
    }{
```

which yields, with

```
\nocite{bertram}
\nocite{doody}
\nocite{shore}
```

the result

[image]

Observe that the bib entries

```
@article{doody,
  author       = {Doody, Terrence},
  title        = {Hemingway's Style and Jake's Narration},
  year         = 1974,

@article{shore,
  author       = {Shore, Bradd},
  title        = {Twice-Born, Once Conceived},
  journaltitle = {American Anthropologist},
  date         = {1991-03},
```

already show a certain amount of variation with respect to the source of the "year" field, so this approach seems to offer some robustness.

**Disclaimer:** I know nothing at all about `biber`, `biblatex` or `moderntimeline`, so there might be hidden mantraps I don't recognize.

**Update:** As the last `.` is indeed hardcoded in `\cventry`, it needs to be removed by adding this patch after `\moderncvstyle{classic}`:

```
\moderncvstyle{classic}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}    

\xpatchcmd\cventry{.\strut}{\strut}{}{}
```

[image]

Comment: This is beautiful. would you happen to know how to remove the last "dot" though? I think it comes automatically from `tldatelabelcventry`

Comment: @Trefex I didn't notice... Whoa, the `.` is indeed hardcoded in `\cventry`, so it must be removed with a patch. See edit.