# Publication list ordered by year using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

Additional to the references I want to create a list of publication which should be ordered by year.
Audrey has already published a [solution that does something similar for a CV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123818).
However, with every first entry for a certain year an indent is inserted, which I want to avoid (in the figure the blue marked indent).

How can I achieve that all lines and entries are left aligned and no indent is created at the first line of a certain year?

```
% !BIB program = biber
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, maxnames=99, giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{identifier1,
 Title = {Some really awesome long title: And some further information},
 Author = {Goossens, Michel and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
 Booktitle = {An Booktitle with additional content: Some Book about the Future},
 Year = {2004},
 Pages = {1--42}
}
@InProceedings{identifier2,
 Title = {Some really awesome long title: And some further information},
 Author = {Goossens, Michel and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
 Booktitle = {An Booktitle with additional content: Some Book about the Future},
 Year = {2004},
 Pages = {1--42}
}
@InProceedings{identifier3,
 Title = {Some really awesome long title: And some further information},
 Author = {Goossens, Michel and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
 Booktitle = {An Booktitle with additional content: First edition},
 Year = {2000},
 Pages = {1--100}
}
@InProceedings{identifier4,
 Title = {Some really awesome long title: And some further information},
 Author = {Goossens, Michel and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
 Booktitle = {An Booktitle with additional content: Third edition},
 Year = {1995},
 Pages = {1--100}
}
@InProceedings{identifier5,
 Title = {Some really awesome long title: And some further information},
 Author = {First Author, Second Author, Third Author },
 Booktitle = {An okay Booktitle First Special Edition},
 Year = {1994},
 Pages = {1--100}
}
@Book{test1,
 author = {Goossens, Michel and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
 title = {Some really awesome long title: And some further information},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
 location = {Reading, Mass.},
 year = {1994},
}
@Book{test2,
 author = {Mittelbach, F. and Goossens, Michel and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Samarin, Alexander},
 title = {The LaTeX Companion Ninth Special Edition},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
 location = {Reading, Mass.},
 year = {1995},
}
@Book{test3,
 author = {Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Goossens, Michel},
 title = {The LaTeX Companion First Special Edition},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
 location = {Reading, Mass.},
 year = {2004},
} 
@Book{test4,
 author = {Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Goossens, Michel},
 title = {The LaTeX Companion Third Special Edition},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
 location = {Reading, Mass.},
 year = {1995},
} 
@Book{test5,
 author = {Mittelbach, F. and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Goossens, Michel and Samarin, Alexander},
 title = {The LaTeX Companion Second Special Edition},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
 location = {Reading, Mass.},
 year = {2000},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibenvironment{myPublicationListYearStyle}{
 \list{%
  \iffieldequals{year}{\bibyear}
  {}
  {\printfield{year}\savefield{year}{\bibyear}}%
 }{%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
  \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
  \leftmargin\labelwidth%
  \advance\leftmargin\labelsep%
 }%
 \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}%
}%
{\endlist}
{\item}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\newpage
\section*{List of publications}
\nocite{*}
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=ydnt]{}
\printbibliography[heading=none, env=myPublicationListYearStyle]
\end{refcontext}

\end{document}
```

[image: The blue marked indent should be avoided]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `myPublicationListYearStyle` reserves too little space for the year. When there is too little space for the list label, the remaining entry gets pushed to the right a bit.

With

```
\defbibenvironment{myPublicationListYearStyle}{
 \list{%
  \iffieldequals{year}{\bibyear}
  {}
  {\printfield{year}\savefield{year}{\bibyear}}%
 }{%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
  \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
  \leftmargin\labelwidth%
  \advance\leftmargin\labelsep%
 }%
 \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}%
}%
{\endlist}
{\item}
```

you reserve the same amount of space for the year as you reserve for the numeric labels in the other bibliography. The largest label in the bibliography is "[10]", but the years are longer than that ("2000").

It is easiest to manually reserve a suitable amount of space by setting `\labelwidth` to a sensible value (in the example I chose `2em`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, maxnames=99, giveninits=true]{biblatex}


\defbibenvironment{myPublicationListYearStyle}
  {\list
     {\iffieldequals{year}{\bibyear}
        {}
        {\printfield{year}\savefield{year}{\bibyear}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{2em}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \leftmargin\labelwidth%
      \advance\leftmargin\labelsep}%
   \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}%
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{identifier1,
 Title = {Some really awesome long title: And some further information},
 Author = {Goossens, Michel and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
 Booktitle = {An Booktitle with additional content: Some Book about the Future},
 Year = {2004},
 Pages = {1--42}
}
@InProceedings{identifier2,
 Title = {Some really awesome long title: And some further information},
 Author = {Goossens, Michel and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
 Booktitle = {An Booktitle with additional content: Some Book about the Future},
 Year = {2004},
 Pages = {1--42}
}
@InProceedings{identifier3,
 Title = {Some really awesome long title: And some further information},
 Author = {Goossens, Michel and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
 Booktitle = {An Booktitle with additional content: First edition},
 Year = {2000},
 Pages = {1--100}
}
@InProceedings{identifier4,
 Title = {Some really awesome long title: And some further information},
 Author = {Goossens, Michel and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
 Booktitle = {An Booktitle with additional content: Third edition},
 Year = {1995},
 Pages = {1--100}
}
@InProceedings{identifier5,
 Title = {Some really awesome long title: And some further information},
 Author = {First Author, Second Author, Third Author },
 Booktitle = {An okay Booktitle First Special Edition},
 Year = {1994},
 Pages = {1--100}
}
@Book{test1,
 author = {Goossens, Michel and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
 title = {Some really awesome long title: And some further information},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
 location = {Reading, Mass.},
 year = {1994},
}
@Book{test2,
 author = {Mittelbach, F. and Goossens, Michel and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Samarin, Alexander},
 title = {The LaTeX Companion Ninth Special Edition},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
 location = {Reading, Mass.},
 year = {1995},
}
@Book{test3,
 author = {Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Goossens, Michel},
 title = {The LaTeX Companion First Special Edition},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
 location = {Reading, Mass.},
 year = {2004},
} 
@Book{test4,
 author = {Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Goossens, Michel},
 title = {The LaTeX Companion Third Special Edition},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
 location = {Reading, Mass.},
 year = {1995},
} 
@Book{test5,
 author = {Mittelbach, F. and Mouse, Mickey and Pan, Peter and Goossens, Michel and Samarin, Alexander},
 title = {The LaTeX Companion Second Special Edition},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
 location = {Reading, Mass.},
 year = {2000},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\newpage
\section*{List of publications}
\nocite{*}
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=ydnt]{}
\printbibliography[heading=none, env=myPublicationListYearStyle]
\end{refcontext}

\end{document}
```

[image: Nicely aligned years.]