# Referencing custom command inside bst file

Tags: bibtex, bst

I'm writing a bst file so that I could list my publications using bibtex inside moderncv class document, based on this article: https://www.sethajacobson.com/notes/2021/3/1/to-bold-and-italicize-specific-author-names-in-a-latex-generated-citation . Also note that my bst file is based on the following post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85983/81910 .

Following exactly as described in the article did produce desired result; it indeed made my name boldface.

While replicating this article, I found that I need to put my name inside the bst file. This is quite undesirable if I want to change my name quickly. I tried adding

```
\newcommand{\myname}{I. M. Author}
```

into my tex file and modified the `bold.if.imauthor` function as

```
FUNCTION {bold.if.imauthor}
    { duplicate$ purify$ 
    "\myname"
    purify$ = { 
    "\textbf{"
    swap$ * "}" * } 'skip$ if$
}
```

But, this does not work.

Questions are:

1. Why does this not work?
2. How do I define my name in the main tex file so that I could change which name to be highlighted without editing the bst file?

Comment: 1. When `bibtex` is run, it does not look at your `tex` file; it looks only at the `aux` file for which bibitems are cited, and generates a corresponding `bbl` file from the `bst` file. // 2. That is against the reason for a `bst` file: it defines a bibliographic _style_ which is supposed to be usable by many different `tex` files.

Comment: Instead of trying to hack `bibtex` into doing something it would only reluctantly do, it may be a lot easier to just use `biblatex`. You can use the same `bib` file, but can program these kinds of operations as part of your `tex` file. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73136/119