# Bibtex .bst file modification to include alphabetical ordering

Tags: bibtex, sorting

Is it possible to modify [the JHEP bibliography style](http://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP/TeXclass/DOCS/JHEP.bst) in a simple way such that it displays bibliographical entries in alphabetical order, instead of basing on first appearence in the main text?

(Addendum) Is it possible to add in the same way a function that prints a long horizontal line ----- instead of the name of the author(s) if these are repeated, as is done e.g. by the amsplain.bst style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bibliography style `JHEP` seems to be a lightly modified version of the venerable `unsrt` style. To enable alphabetical sorting of the entries, you should modify `JHEP.bst` as follows. (Aside: I'm not sure if this procedure satisfies your objective that the modifications be done "in a simple way". However, I've tried out the code, and it seems to work!)

- Make a copy of the file `JHEP.bst`. Call the copy (say) `JHEPsort.bst`. (Don't edit the original file directly.)
- Open the file `JHEPsort.bst` in a text editor. The editor you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Locate the lines

  ```
  MACRO {pr} {"Phys. Rev."}

  READ

  STRINGS { longest.label }
  ```

  in this file. Hint: In my copy of this file, this excerpt starts on l. 1048.
- Insert the following 145 or so lines **between** the line `READ` and the line `STRINGS { longest.label }`:

  ```
  FUNCTION {sortify}
  { purify$
    "l" change.case$
  }

  INTEGERS { len }

  FUNCTION {chop.word}
  { 's :=
    'len :=
    s #1 len substring$ =
      { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
      's
    if$
  }

  FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
  { 's :=
    #1 'nameptr :=
    ""
    s num.names$ 'numnames :=
    numnames 'namesleft :=
      { namesleft #0 > }
      { nameptr #1 >
          { "   " * }
          'skip$
        if$
        s nameptr "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  ff{ }}{  jj{ }}" format.name$ 't :=
        nameptr numnames = t "others" = and
          { "et al" * }
          { t sortify * }
        if$
        nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
        namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
      }
    while$
  }

  FUNCTION {sort.format.title}
  { 't :=
    "A " #2
      "An " #3
        "The " #4 t chop.word
  chop.word
    chop.word
    sortify
    #1 global.max$ substring$
  }

  FUNCTION {author.sort}
  { author empty$
      { key empty$
          { "to sort, need author or key in " cite$ * warning$
            ""
          }
          { key sortify }
        if$
      }
      { author sort.format.names }
    if$
  }

  FUNCTION {author.editor.sort}
  { author empty$
      { editor empty$
          { key empty$
              { "to sort, need author, editor, or key in " cite$ * warning$
                ""
              }
              { key sortify }
            if$
          }
          { editor sort.format.names }
        if$
      }
      { author sort.format.names }
    if$
  }

  FUNCTION {author.organization.sort}
  { author empty$
      { organization empty$
          { key empty$
              { "to sort, need author, organization, or key in " cite$ * warning$
                ""
              }
              { key sortify }
            if$
          }
          { "The " #4 organization chop.word sortify }
        if$
      }
      { author sort.format.names }
    if$
  }

  FUNCTION {editor.organization.sort}
  { editor empty$
      { organization empty$
          { key empty$
              { "to sort, need editor, organization, or key in " cite$ * warning$
                ""
              }
              { key sortify }
            if$
          }
          { "The " #4 organization chop.word sortify }
        if$
      }
      { editor sort.format.names }
    if$
  }

  FUNCTION {presort}
  { type$ "book" =
    type$ "inbook" =
    or
      'author.editor.sort
      { type$ "proceedings" =
      'editor.organization.sort
          { type$ "manual" =
              'author.organization.sort
              'author.sort
            if$
          }
        if$
      }
    if$
    "    "
    *
    year field.or.null sortify
    *
    "    "
    *
    title field.or.null
    sort.format.title
    *
    #1 entry.max$ substring$
    'sort.key$ :=
  }

  ITERATE {presort}

  SORT
  ```

  Just in case you're curious where this code comes from: I certainly did not create it myself! Instead, I copied it from the bibliography style file `plain.bst`.
- Save the file `JHEPsort.bst` either to the directory that contains your main tex file or to a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, you will probably need to update the filename database of your TeX distribution, in a way that's appropriate for your TeX distribution.
- Start using the new bibliography style by providing the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{JHEPsort}
  ```

  instead of `\bibliographystyle{JHEP}`. Be sure to run LateX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more so that all changes are fully propagated.

Happy BibTeXing!

Comment: very nice, that's precisely what I was looking for. One last fancy gadget: is it possible to add in the same way a function that prints a long horizontal line ----- instead of the name of the author(s) if these are repeated, as is done e.g. by the amsplain.bst style?

Comment: @jj_p - Once one starts making more than just one or two changes to an existing bst file, it's usually better to start from scratch by running the `makebst` utility of the [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package. It presents a straightforward, menu-driven set of queries along with possible answers; the default answer is generally marked very clearly. Based on your answers it'll build a bespoke bst file. Give it a try. :-)

Comment: right, but there's still the issue that this class is particularly suited to be compatible with inspire, arXiv etc., so maybe modifying it is still worth some effort; do you think it is too involved task?

Comment: @jj_p - How long do you want the line to be: the length of two or three em-dashes, or something else?

Comment: yes, something like to3em should do; the hard work seems more in implementing the prev.author this.author story

Comment: Thanks to another answer of yours, I was able to introduce in a consistent way the bysame story, and achieve the above goal :)

Comment: @jj_p - I assume you're referring to my answer to the posting [dash instead of repeated author name](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80316/5001), right? I was starting to remember vaguely having written just such an answer sometime in the past and was about to look it up when I saw your latest comment. Glad you saved me this effort! :-)