# How to change a .bst for references sorted in order of appearance

Tags: bibtex, sorting, lncs

I've been struggling trying to format my references for a paper which needs to follow the LNCS guidelines. They use to provide a .bst file which formats the references exactly as they require, but the only issue is that the references are sorted in alphabetical order, and now it seems they require them sorted in order of appearance. Is there any way of tuning the .bst in order to get the references sorted in order of appearance?  Anyone had the same problem?

Here the template (including the .bst) I am using: ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs2e.zip

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: If I use `\bibliographystyle{splncs}` the references are in order of appearance.

Comment: Could you please indicate a link to download the splncs.bst, or the full template you are using? At least the splncs03.bst (which is inside the template I am pointing to) does not format in order of appearance. Thanks

Comment: You find it at ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/splncs.bst

Comment: Note that the order of appearance was an old habit around 2007 of LNCS. The alphabetical sorting was the new requirement. That leads me to the question: What do you mean by "they require"? Can you provide us an URL with that requirement?

Comment: I replaced bibliography style `\bibliographystyle{splncs04}` with `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I sent an email to springer and they sent me a bst file which formats the references according to their guidelines, but does not sort the references in alphabetical order. You can download here:  http://www.filedropper.com/splncs03unsrt

Comment: Link just takes me to the main filedropper page. Is an account required to get the file?

Comment: The link is dead!

Comment: You can find it in ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/svproc/templates/ProcSci_TeX.zip

Answer (score 7):

The zip file has only `splncs03.bst` which uses alphabetical order. However, Springer also provides `splncs.bst` that uses order of appearance. You can download it at

ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/splncs.bst

Comment: Thanks, I found this one as well, but even though this one sorts in order of appearance, it seems it does not format according to the latest springerNCS requirements (i.e. the volume is in bold, and the pages appear after the Year). As far as I know, these are the latest guidelines: http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/1121537/application/pdf/Springer_CS_Proceedings_Author_Guidelines_March14.pdf

Any ideas on how to meet these guidelines?

Comment: @user51083 I'm rather surprised that the guidelines tell you to do something that the provided styles don't allow.

Comment: Yes, I am surprised as well. I sent an email to springer, let's see what they suggest...

Comment: @user51083 have they ever replied?

Comment: Yes, actually They sent me a bst file with the correct formatting and without sorting. Sorry for the late reply:
http://www.filedropper.com/splncs03unsrt

Comment: This is not recommended ... `splncs.bst` is the old BibTeX style for use with `llncs.cls`. Check out [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273937/52025).

Comment: Can you please upload splncs03unsrt.bst online.

Comment: ftp link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `.bst` file that they've given as a starting point i.e. `splncs03.bst` ... make a copy of it and rename it to something like `splncs04.bst`. And then simply comment out `ITERATE {presort}`. Do not change original files!

I'd not recommend using old `.bst` files that they used to provide. `splncs.bst` is the old BibTeX style for use with `llncs.cls`. `splncs_srt.bst` is just like the previous but with alphabetic sorting and `splncs03.bst` is the current LNCS BibTeX style with alphabetic sorting.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Hi faced same problem and found the results in :

Just need to do the reverse of : 
[Bibtex .bst file modification to include alphabetical ordering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174458/bibtex-bst-file-modification-to-include-alphabetical-ordering)

Remove all code(a lot of functions with sortify or some sort) in the bst file between the

READ

STRINGS { longest.label }

Comment: It probably suffices to remove -- or comment out -- two lines: the ones that say `ITERATE {presort}` and `SORT`; they occur just before the line that says `STRINGS { longest.label }`. Deleting all ca 150 lines won't hurt, though...

Comment: Deleting all the lines or commenting out `ITERATE {presort}` can make Bibtex crash at times. Commenting out `SORT` (at *all* places where it appears) should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. After searching a lot, I found the problem. Basically, the latest `splncs04.bst` automatically sorts according to the alphabetical order of the last name of the author. This is the latest Springer Style.

But if you want to have the citation numbers to be ordered by appearance, you have to use a different style file. For this, I have used `splncs03_unsrt.bst`. You can download the file from the link [here](ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/svproc/templates/ProcSci_TeX.zip). This will sort the citations in the order of the appearance.

For more information, you can refer to this thread. I got the help from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/552856/220075).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use also `LastName,FirstName`, so this was my solution:
Use this topic: [Displaying author's name in a bibliographic entry in the form: Surname, First Initial of Firstname](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131087/displaying-authors-name-in-a-bibliographic-entry-in-the-form-surname-first-in) but change the file `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bst\base\unsrt.bst`, instead of `plainnat`.

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

In the bst, before "STRINGS { longest.label }" there should be a command "SORT"; you can comment that out. Then the order of citation will be the order of reference.

Comment: There are some files where the standalone command "SORT" appears multiple times. Then, all these statements should be commented out.