# bibliographystyle 'splncs04': wrong ordering

Tags: bibliographies

I'm writing a paper using the template of Springer Lecture Notes in Computer Science. The template comes with `splncs04.bst` file for bibliography style.
My bibliography is a `.bib` file generated with Mendeley.

Now, when I compile the tex file, using `\bibliographystyle{splncs04}` (as requested by the template), citations are reported not in order: first citation is n. 12, then 8, then 5 and so on. 
If I compile using a different style, like `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`, the order is correct: it starts from 1.

Do you know it this behaviour is correct? It seems strange to me that `splncs style` does not care about ordering.

Comment: I assume the citations are ordered alphabetically (by author name). Can you confirm this? In any case I think you can assume that normally the sort order produced by `splncs04` is as desired by Springer. So as long as you can rule out an error on your side, you should be fine.

Comment: You are completely right: with splncs04 citations are ordered alphabetically. This makes sense, thanks.

Comment: i found the solution here: https://www.baeldung.com/cs/latex-bibtex-sort-references You have to comment two lines of code at the splncs04.bst
%ITERATE {presort}
%SORT That works.

Answer (score 2):

`splncs04.bst` orders the references alphabetically and not by appearance in the text.

Since this is a publisher class I don't think it would be a good idea to try to modify this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. After searching a lot, I found the problem. Basically, the latest `splncs04.bst` automatically sorts according to the alphabetical order of the last name of the author. This is the latest Springer Style.

But if you want to have the citation numbers to be ordered by appearance, you have to use a different style file. For this, I have used `splncs03_unsrt.bst`. You can download the file from the link [here](ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/svproc/templates/ProcSci_TeX.zip). This will sort the citations in the order of the appearance.

For more information, you can refer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231631) thread. I got the help from here.

Comment: This helped me a lot!