# Order references alphabetically with "elsarticle-num-names.bst"

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, cross-referencing, citing, natbib

How Can I order my references alphabetically using the bibliographystyle "elsarticle-num-names.bst"?

Here is a MWE, copied from the elsarticle template folder itself:

elsarticle-template.tex:

```
\documentclass[preprint]{elsarticle}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\end{frontmatter}

Here are two sample references: \cite{Feynman1963118,Dirac1953888}.

\section*{References}
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```

mybibfile.bib:

```
@article{Dirac1953888,
  title   = "The lorentz transformation and absolute time",
  journal = "Physica ",
  volume  = "19",
  number  = "1-–12",
  pages   = "888--896",
  year    = "1953",
  doi     = "10.1016/S0031-8914(53)80099-6",
  author  = "P.A.M. Dirac"
}

@article{Feynman1963118,
  title   = "The theory of a general quantum system interacting with a linear dissipative system",
  journal = "Annals of Physics ",
  volume  = "24",
  pages   = "118--173",
  year    = "1963",
  doi     = "10.1016/0003-4916(63)90068-X",
  author  = "R.P Feynman and F.L {Vernon Jr.}"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Aren't they by default?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: No. The order by default is the order of appearance in the text. I need that order alphabetically by author lastname.

Comment: Can you please give us a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Answer (score 4):

This style already uses the sorting function. You can edit sort function **bib.sort.order** in your .bst file. It is very good described on [Bibtex .bst file modification to include alphabetical ordering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174458/104565). I hope it will help you.

Comment: Finally I managed to do this! I had to copy, from the link you mentioned, only the functions "FUNCTION {author.organization.sort}" and "FUNCTION {editor.organization.sort}", and then copy the contents of "FUNCTION {presort}" into  "FUNCTION {bib.sort.order}". This solved the problem!

Comment: For reference: here is the modified file that works for me: https://github.com/erelsgl/erelsgl.github.io/blob/master/papers/elsarticle-num-names-alpha.bst

Answer (score 0):

The way references are ordered is controlled by the *.bst* file. If you want to change the ordering, then you need to modify that file.

Here is how you can modify your *elsarticle-num-names.bst* file in order to have your references sorted alphabetically. I suggest creating a copy of that file and name it *elsarticle-names.bst* before modifying it.

First, locate the *presort* function in that *.bst* file. It may look like this:

```
FUNCTION {presort}
{ calc.label
 label sortify
 "    "
 *
 seq.num #1 + 'seq.num :=
 seq.num  int.to.fix
 'sort.label :=
 sort.label
 *
 "    "
 *
 title field.or.null
 sort.format.title
 *
 #1 entry.max$ substring$
 'sort.key$ :=
}
```

Then, replace it with the following:

```
FUNCTION {presort}
{ calc.label
  label sortify
  "    "
  *
  type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.sort
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.sort
        'author.sort
      if$
    }
  if$
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.label :=
  sort.label
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}
```

There are also several alternate *.bst* files provided by Elsevier (with or without alphabetical sorting) in the **sample manuscript** available [here](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions#elsevier). It should be reminded however that, if you intend to submit an article to a scientific journal, you should use the *.bst* file provided by the editor for that specific journal without modification. There are indeed strict guidelines that you must comply with regarding formatting of the bibliography.