# BibTex: Replacing repeated authors in a list of authors with em-dashes

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm using a .bst file provided by my discipline ([ametsoc2014.bst](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/ametsoc/ametsoc2014.bst)) to create my references section using BibTex. However, this file really is incomplete according to their suggested specifications. In particular, it doesn't allow for replacement of repeated authors with em-dashes. I've modified the code according to the suggestions of Mico [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80316/dash-instead-of-repeated-author-name). This works when *all* authors for any two references are the same. However, the style guide for my discipline mandates that any references with the same first author (and any additional authors) have these authors replaced by dashes like:

```
Doswell, C. A., and E. N. Rasmussen, 1994: The Effect of Neglecting   
    the Virtual Temperature Correction on CAPE Calculations. Wea.   
    Forecast., 9, 625–629.  

——, R. Davies-Jones, and D. L. Keller, 1990: On Summary Measures of
    Skill in Rare Event Forecasting Based on Contingency Tables. Wea.
    Forecast., 5, 576–585.
```

where both papers have the same first author (Doswell, C.A.), but have different authors after that. Or like:

```
Fawbush, E., and R. Miller, 1952: A mean sounding representative of the
    tornadic airmass environment. Bull. Amer. Meteor. Soc, 33, 303–307.
——, and ——, 1954: The types of air masses in which North American  
    tornadoes form. Bull. Amer. Meteor. Soc, 35, 154–165.
——, ——, and L. Starrett, 1951: An empirical method of forecasting 
    tornado development. Bull. Amer. Meteor. Soc, 32, 1–9.
```

where all three papers have the same first 2 authors (Fawbush, E.  and R. Miller), but the third paper has a third author, L. Starrett.

Is there any way to parse through the authors like this to add dashes when necessary?

Comment: +1 in that I would love to see whether and how this can be achieved. But if the official bst file provided by your discipline doesn't implement it, I think it is good justification that you shouldn't feel obligated to implement it either.

Comment: So something similar to what I want is implemented in [aer.bst](https://www.sonoma.edu/users/b/bouvet/aer.bst), but I'm not versed enough in .bst syntax to know how to implement it in to my .bst file.